# Count number of nonempty entries in each column of, e.g., comm output

Tags: bash, unix, awk

The Unix command `comm file1 file2` has a 3 column output with lines unique to file1 in the first column, lines unique to file2 in the second, and lines shared by both in the 3rd (assuming file1 and file2 are sorted). It ends up looking something like this:

```
$ echo -e "alpha\nbravo\ncharlie" > file1
$ echo -e "alpha\nbravo\ndelta" > file2
$ comm file1 file2
                alpha
                bravo
charlie
        delta
```

If I want the number of nonempty lines in each column, is there a general way to parse the output of `comm` and count those?

I know that for `comm` in particular I could just run

```
for i in {12,23,31}; do comm -$i file1 file2 | wc -l; done
```

but I'm curious about solutions that take the `comm` output file as a starting point, for the sake of getting better at Unix command line. I added the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) tag because I have a hunch there's a good awk solution.

Comment: You should include tabs in your sample input as that has a big impact on the possible solutions (I actually don't think a robust solution is possible but I haven't thought it through). Also include the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer covers your question of using `awk` to do the job quite well, but it is also worth mentioning that the GNU version of comm has a `--total` option which will print the sum of each column in a similar manner.

Comment: Of course you can disable the usual output if you are just interested in the totals: `comm -123 --total file1 file2`.

Comment: For those without the --total option, it was added in version 8.26: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/NEWS

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```
comm file1 file2 |
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\n' '{ if ($1=="") if ($2=="") c3++; else c2++; else c1++ }
END { print c3, c2, c1 }'
```

```
2
1
1
```

Note that output of `comm` is tab delimited with these cases:

- 1st and 2nd empty column in common lines
- 1st empty column in lines unique to file2
- 1st non-empty column in lines unique to file1

Comment: That would fail if any of the output lines contained tabs (due to an input line that contains tabs).

Comment: This will still fail if any of the input files is tab delimited or has a tab in there.

Comment: @kvantour; No, that's not the case as long as lines don't start with a tab

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, that is much shorter and easier to read (edited)

Comment: Your logic is sound, but as you indicate, fails if one line starts with a <tab>. (+1 for awesomeness of logic)

Answer (score 1):

The question is interesting, but not as easy as one would imagine, especially if you do not have the `--total` option.

**A couple of things about `comm`:**

1. `comm` works on *sorted* files
2. if a line appears *n* times in `file1` and *m* times *n < m* times in `file2`, `comm` will output *n-m* entries in column 2 and *n* entries in column 3.

   ```
   $ comm <(echo -e "1\n2\n3") <(echo "2\n2\n3\n4")
   1
                   2
           2
                   3
           4
   ```
3. `comm` uses <tab>-character as a default separator, processing its output becomes problematic if your input contains this character.

   ```
   $ comm  <(echo -e "1\t2\n3") <(echo "2\n3\n4")
   1       2             << this is the weird line
           2
                   3
           4
   ```

   Luckily it has an option to define the delimiter (`--output-delimiter=STR`)
4. `comm` only adds a delimiter if other non-empty fields are following

   ```
   $ comm  --output-delimiter=SEP <(echo -e "1\n2\n3") <(echo "2\n3\n4")
   1             << NO SEP (1 field)
   SEPSEP2       << TWO SEP (3 fields)
   SEPSEP3       << TWO SEP (3 fields)
   SEP4          << ONE SEP (2 fields)
   ```

**How can we solve it now:**

We should clearly not use an ASCII symbol as a delimiter, this is asking for problems when processing ASCII files, so what you can do is use a non-printable character as a delimiter. You could use for example <start-of-heading>-character with octal value `\001` (it does not accept the <null>-character). This generally solves the issues you might have due to point (3)

```
$ comm  --output-delimiter=$'\001' <(echo -e "1\t2\n3") <(echo "2\n3\n4")
```

this output can now be piped into an extremely simple `awk`

```
$ awk -F "\001" '{a[NF]++}END{print a[1],a[2],a[3] }'
```

the above works because of point (4).

So you can just do:

```
$ comm  --output-delimiter=$'\001' file1 file2 \
  | awk -F "\001" '{a[NF]++}END{print a[1],a[2],a[3] }'
```

**But I don't have that `--output-delimiter` option:** This calls for the pure `awk` solution. We keep track of 3 arrays. `a` for `file1` `b` for `file2` and `c` for the combination. (`c` keeps track of all the entries). We make sure to keep point (2) into account.

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR) { a[$0]++; c[$0]++ }
       (NR!=FNR) { b[$0]++; c[$0]-- }
       END { for(i in c) {
                if      (c[i] <  0) { countb+=-c[i]; countc+=a[i] }
                else if (c[i] == 0) {                countc+=a[i] }
                else                { counta+= c[i]; countc+=b[i] }
             }
             print counta, countb, countc
       }' file1 file2
```

We could essentially get rid of the array `b` as it can be derived from `a` and `c`, but I wanted to make it a bit more clear how it works; the other version would be:

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR) { a[$0]++; c[$0]++; next } { c[$0]-- }
       END { for(i in c) {
               counta+=(c[i]>0 ? c[i] : 0)
               countb-=(c[i]<0 ? c[i] : 0)
               countc+=a[i] - (c[i]>0 ? c[i] : 0)
             }
             print counta, countb, countc
       }' file1 file2
```

Comment: Very nice use of `--output-delimiter`, I guess that is available on `gnu` version

Answer (score 0):

obviously you can do all in `awk` without `comm` or requiring sorted inputs.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
               {if($1 in a) {c3++; delete a[$1]} 
                else c2++} 
           END {print length(a),c2,c3}' file1 file2

1 1 2
```

that's counts for file1 only, file2 only, and common.

Note, this requires that the records are unique in each file.

Comment: This will only work correctly if the lines are unique in the files. `comm` operates differently.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$  comm file1 file2 | perl -lne ' /^\t\t/ and $kv{2}++; /^\t\S+/ and $kv{1}++; /^\S+/ and $kv{3}++; END { print "col-$_:$kv{$_}" for(keys %kv) } '
col-3:1
col-1:1
col-2:2

$
```

or

```
$ comm file1 file2 | perl -lne ' /(^\t\t)|(^\t\S+)|(^.)/ and $x=$+[0]>2?3:$+[0]; $kv{$x}++; END { print "col-$_:$kv{$_}" for(keys %kv) } '
col-3:1
col-1:1
col-2:2

$
```

where 
`col-1 -> first file`

`col-3 -> second file`

`col-2 -> both file`